# Sub menu not showing at hover

Tags: html, css, hover, submenu

http://www.easysystems.nl/onze-klanten/

At this website and on the page "onze klanten" when hovering over the menu, the submenu dissapears behind the slider.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Try to set z-index for <li> which is inside "sub-menu"

Answer (score 2):

Make the container have a `z-index: 101` to appear over the image slider element:

```
#container {
   position: relative;
   z-index: 101;
}
```

The problem here was that the image slider has a `z-index` of `100`, and that will make it appear on top of the elements that have a lower or no z-index (or positioned `static`ly)